# Error when running cmd <rake db:migrate> - "No connection pool with 'primary' found"

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord, migration, sinatra

I'm trying to set up a SQLite Db for my sinatra app and am running into an error I can't figure out. I've looked up related questions but none of them have helped.

Up to this point I've run `bundle exec rake db:create_migration NAME=create_budget`
which created a migration in my db folder.

However when I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get the following error message:

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found.`

I am following the tutorial https://learn.co/lessons/sinatra-activerecord-setup

database.yml - the instructions did not say to create this but in researching the error this seemed to keep coming up. This is still magic to me as a learn so I'm not sure if activerecord requires this or not.

```
 # SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Migrate: created with the `db:create_migration`

```
# Database Migration
class CreateBudget < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :budget do |t|
      t.string :description
      t.string :amount
    end
  end
end
```

GemFile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) { |repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

# gem "rails"

gem 'activerecord'
gem 'rake'
gem 'require_all'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord'
gem 'slim'
gem 'thin'

group :development do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'shotgun'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'tux'
end
```

File structure - not sure if this will be helpful or not

[image: FilePath]

Comment: Looks like I need to run `rake db:create` first. It's either missing from this tutorial or I overlooked it. I have an error when running that. Will update if it provides the fix.

Comment: Now when I run `rake db:create` I get the following error   `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not 
    configured. Available: [].` Thoughts?

Comment: same problem, I am still trying to solve, I been searching on Google and read page after page. annoying. can't pinpoint problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle exec rake db:create:all`